# Setting attribute of a PyQt5 widget created in a subclass within the main class

Tags: python, pyqt5

I made a program and want to rewrite it with classes.
I don't know how to change the text of a `Qlabel` created in a subclass *outside* of it.
Here the code:

```
import sys
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QWidget, QVBoxLayout, QLabel

class MainWindow(QWidget):

    def __init__(self):
        super(MainWindow, self).__init__()
        self.setMinimumSize(300,200)
        self.layout  = QVBoxLayout()
        self.layout.addWidget(MyClass(self))
        self.setLayout(self.layout)
        # i want to change the text label from here
        # with label.setText()

class MyClass(QWidget):

    def __init__(self, parent):
        super(MyClass, self).__init__()
        self.parent = parent
        self.label = QLabel("My text",self)
        self.label.setStyleSheet("color: black;")
        self.label.setGeometry(5, 0, 65, 15) 

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    root = MainWindow()
    root.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Thank you

Comment: You question is unclear. Where are you attempting to change the text of a `Qlabel` created in a subclass outside of it? What happened, was there an error message?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not necessary to pass the parent, just use the object reference:

```py
class MainWindow(QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(MainWindow, self).__init__(parent)
        self.setMinimumSize(300,200)
        self.layout  = QVBoxLayout()
        self.myclass = MyClass()
        self.layout.addWidget(self.myclass)
        self.setLayout(self.layout)
        # i want to change the text label from here
        self.myclass.label.setText("Foo")

class MyClass(QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(MyClass, self).__init__(parent)
        self.label = QLabel("My text",self)
        self.label.setStyleSheet("color: black;")
        self.label.setGeometry(5, 0, 65, 15)
```

Comment: thank you, i've already find the solution but made a mistake when i post it. is it important to put parent=none in the declaration ?